# Need help regarding Template class instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

Let me present my problem with an example :

```
template <typename T> class a{
public:
    T data;
    a():data(T()){}
    a(T temp): data(temp) {}
};
```

So if write in `main()` like

```
a(30);
a("String");
```

So according to the template argument deduction rule , it should be able to generate the first temporary class as `a<int>(30)` etc

But I the error which says:

> missing template arguments before '(' token

so why this happens, this is only true for function template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template parameter deduction from arguments only works for *functions*, never for *classes*. Until you know the type of the class, i.e. all its template parameters, you don't even know which member functions the class has!

So, you always have to say the template parameters if you want to construct an object directly:

```
a<int> x(30);
```

---

Here's a little thought experiment to expand on the above. Suppose we have

```
template <typename T> class Foo;
```

and we are calling `Foo::somefunction(x);`, where `x` is some type. You think, well, I declared `somefunction()` like this:

```
template <typename T> class Foo
{
  static void somefunction(const T & x);
};
```

so it should be obvious that `T` is the same type as the type of `x`. But now imagine I have a specialization:

```
template <> class Foo<char>
{
  static void anotherfunction(double x);
};
```

The class `Foo<char>` doesn't even *have* a function `somefunction()`, so the expression `Foo::somefunction(x)` doesn't even get to the stage where I could look up the argument!

The usual way around this is to make a free helper function that constructs your object:

```
template <typename T> a<T> make_a(const T & x) { return a<T>(x); }
```

Since this is a *function* template, its parameters *can* be deduced:

```
make_a(30);      // type a<int>
make_a("hello"); // type a<char[6]>
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is *not* a template, its the class which is a template. So when you write `a(30)`, the template argument deduction *for the class template* cannot be done!

If there exists a constructor template, then the template argument for the templated constructor can be deduced by the compiler. For example here:

```
template <typename T> class A{
public:
    template<typename U>
    A(const U &): {}   //note : it's a constructor template
};

A<char>  obj(30); //U is deduced as int
```

In the above example, only `U` can be deduced, you still have to provide `T`. Its because

- U is a template argument for the constructor template. Template argument deduction can be done in this case.
- T is a template argument for the class template. Template argument deduction cannot be done here.

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't get you around the need to specify the *class* template parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to declare a temporary as, for example, `a<int>(30)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot infer class template arguments from the arguments to the constructor- unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Template type deduction only happens for template functions.  You need to specify the parameters for a template class instantiation .   You can use a function template to deduce the template parameter and return the appropriate type.  In c++0 x you could use auto to hold the instance.  Can't easily write example code for you on my phone!